# C Why does the for loop only not iterate as many times as its supposed to?

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix

I'm trying to ask K amounts of words to add them in a matrix. 
And i have 2 problems:

1. I tried to make the condition that the strlen(string) must be less than the size of n(matrix size). But when it enters the do while loop, it never quits.
2. How can i make the for loop to repeat until k words are entered?

I already tried a few days ago, and the do while worked fine. Until i changed something and it got messy.

```
/* Enter the matrix dimension */
int n;
do{
    printf("\nEnter the matrix size");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}while(2>n);


/* Ask for the amount of words the user will enter */
int k;
do{
    printf("\nInsert how many words you will enter:");
    scanf("%d", &k);
}while(k<0);

/* k Words loop */
int amountOfWords=0;
char string[20];
int i;
for(i=0; i<k; i++, amountOfWords++)
    {
    do  {
        printf("\nEnter the %d word:\n", amountOfWords+1);
        scanf("%s", &string);
        }while(strlen(string) > n);
    }
```

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in your code. First loop reads `n` greater than or equal to `2`, second loop reads `k` greater than or equal to `0`, and `for` loop reads `k` words whose length are less than or equal to `n`.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with your current code is that the amountOfWords variable is never incremented inside the do-while loop, so the condition for the loop strlen(string) > n is always true.

Here is one way to fix the problem:

```
int amountOfWords=0;
char string[20];
for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
{
    do  {
        printf("\nEnter the %d word:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", string);
    }while(strlen(string) > n);
    amountOfWords++;
}
```

In this way, if the user enters a word that is longer than the maximum size (n), the loop will ask again for a word until a valid word is entered, and the variable amountOfWords will be incremented after a valid word is entered.

Another way to do it could be using a while loop, like this:

```
int amountOfWords=0;
char string[20];
int i=0;
while(amountOfWords<k)
    {
    printf("\nEnter the %d word:\n", amountOfWords+1);
    scanf("%s", string);
    if(strlen(string) <= n) 
        {
        amountOfWords++;
        }
    }
```

In this way, the loop will keep running until amountOfWords reaches the desired amount of words (k).

Comment: The first two `do`'s are used to validate entered values for `n` and `k`.

Comment: When i refer to the do while loop is the one who ask for the strlen(string) one.

Comment: @RobertBaron Updated ny answer